# Selectively control when Aperture/iPhoto opens

Tags: photos.app, aperture, filesystem

Both Aperture and iPhoto have a setting of whether to open "when a camera is connected." I want this option to be checked, but I don't want it to consider my iPad a camera. How can I enable it for some devices but not others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Open Image Capture from the Spotlight (You can also find it in the **Applications** folder)

2) Connect your iPad

3) You should see your device listed under devices column on the left. Select it.

4) In the bottom left, choose "No Application" under the option for choosing which application opens when this device is connected.

[image: image of Image Capture]

Comment: Thank you! I assume it'll automatically launch for other, real cameras still?

Comment: Yes, since those are different devices.